# C++ работа с реестром

Tags: c++, windows, реестр

Написал небольшой код, который должен заменить значение в реестре, все выполняется без ошибок, но значение в реестре не изменяется. Программа запустилась, выполнилась и ничего не произошло... Помогите разобраться в чем моя ошибка...
Вот код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LONG lResult;
    HKEY hKey;
    PCTSTR lpSubKey = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon");

    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,lpSubKey,0,KEY_SET_VALUE,&hKey);

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key not found.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    PCTSTR lpName = TEXT("Shell");
    PCTSTR lpValueEx = "vl.exe";

    lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey,lpName,0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)lpValueEx,(DWORD)(lstrlen(lpValueEx) + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Function fails.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    lResult = RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return 0;
}

И это на выводе
(Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"baner.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"a.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
```

Но думаю это не влияе

Comment: А в чём проблема с вашим выводом? Ну, нет у вам Microsoft'овских pdb, и что?

---
А вот писать в HKLM не из-под рута вам никто не даст, вы с какими правами запускаетесь?

Comment: @VladD пытался запускать exe от администратора, но опять безрезультатно, или я не правильно понимаю?) Эта тема для меня новая, поэтому многого не знаю, но очень хочу реализовать такую программку.

Comment: @LaKO: Хм, у вас 64-битная Windows, да? Тогда может быть вы пали жертвой WOW64 redirection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @VladD Но возможно, но я не знаю, что делать, и в списке предоставленном по ссылке нет моего ключа...

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за наводку, поискал в интернетах, порылся в реестре и нашел куда перенаправляет, надо просто было изменить платформу на 64 битную....

Comment: @VladD Можно ли создать программу, которая бы работала и на 64 битной версии и на 32 битной? Или программу в любом случае придется создавать для каждой версии отдельно?

Comment: Разумеется, можно. Вопрос в том, куда именно вы хотите писать. Ключи можно открывать и без редиректа, но вам придётся понимать, с какой из веток реестра вы работаете. Вот ключи для отключения редиректа: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> SysWOW64

> но значение в реестре не изменяется

Не в том месте ищешь. Ты из 32-битной программы пытаешься менять "64-битную" ветку реестра. Такие изменения пишутся в специальную ветку, куда редеректятся все 32-битные приложения. Именно в ней надо смотреть значение. Это можно сделать либо просматривая соответствующую ветку по её реальному пути, либо запустив 32-битный regedit.

Answer (score 0):

```
PCTSTR lpValueEx = TEXT("vl.exe");
lResult = RegSetValueEx(
                hKey,
                lpName,
                0,
                REG_SZ,
                (LPBYTE)lpValueEx,
                (DWORD)(_tcslen(lpValueEx) + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR)
                );
```

**REG_SZ  

A null-terminated string. This will be either a Unicode or an ANSI string, depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions.**

Comment: Безрезультатно...